# Quick Python Syntax Error

Tags: python

allData is a hash table. key values are product numbers. the value is a list of tuples. The first value in the tuple is either 0,1,2,3 and the second value of the tuple is a list of errors for that number.

```
print len(allData[modelNumber][0][1]) #compiles fine

File "burninprocessor.py", line 467
   bars = [len(allData[modelNumber][0][1]), len(allData[modelNumber][1][1], len(allData[modelNumber][2][1], len(allData[modelNumber][3][1])]
                                                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I should say I'm making a bar graph for each product number. Each graph needs 4 bars, one for errors on 0,1,2, and 3.

Comment: A few closing parens are missing for the `len()` calls.

Comment: you're right sven ty for the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no closing parentheses on the second and third term in your 4-tuple. Try (split across lines for readability here but you probably want to keep it on one line in your code):

```
bars = [len(allData[modelNumber][0][1]), len(allData[modelNumber][1][1]),
        len(allData[modelNumber][2][1]), len(allData[modelNumber][3][1])]
```

Comment: wow you're right. i think i've written too many lines of code today. I was staring at it but couldn't find it.

Comment: sorry got caught up in my code and forgot to mark as solved. nothing personal. thanks again for the help.